# Jersey REST - sending MultivaluedMap to GET causes Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, http, rest, jersey, mime-types

I'm trying to do a parametrized get (aka search). I'm not sure why this is not working. We use the latest jersey dependencies (1.14) and so far all REST interfaces did work just fine. 
Simple REST:

```
@Path("/some/path")
@Component
public class SomeRest {

    @GET
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Response getAll(MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams) {

        // extract params, do search, return response as JSON
        // (Using ObjectMapper.writeValue() to convert object to JSON String)

    }
}
```

The workings of the method are not important I think, as the error states clearly it cannot enter it in the first place due to some unsupported Media type (when I enter my path in the browser):

```
HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type
```

Output is:

```
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap, and Java type javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
....
```

Anyone has an idea?
Thanks!

**edit:**

My goal is to implement a search by using query params with the GET resource. So that when I call `/some/path` I get all results, but if I call `some/path?limit=10&offset=10` I get the second set of 10. I could solve that specific problem with query params but I also want to be able to define where clause params like name=foo in the same parameter map. And those parameters should be dynamic as I want to create a generic getAll method that can take any map of parameters on a GET call.

So the question I guess is: how do I implement dynamic query params?

Comment: Could you post the HTTP request? My guess is that you are confusing FormParams with QueryParams

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confusing query parameters which are in the actual url:

someurl/resource?param1=value1&param2=value2

form url encoded information is same format but the parameters are in the body. Since a GET request does not take a body, you either mean that you want to do a POST, or that you want to use query parameters instead of x-www-form-urlencoded.

Good luck!

EDIT:

You want to use either @QueryParam then if you know exactly what parameters are coming in, or @Context UriInfo if you are not sure how many/what query parameters are going to be expected in the URL.

Comment: Yes, I want to use multiple query parameters for a GET so that I can implement a search on the GET resource.. updated my question..

Answer (score 0):

`@GET` is from [JAX-RS](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr311/index.html). GET request should not contain body. Try the same example with `@POST`

Comment: I think he wants query params like something?param1=value1&param2=... is my guess.

Comment: Hm.. So what should I do, if I want to implement a search? Is that always a post? How can I differentiate between the POST of a create call and the POST of a get call? PS: I think it might even be better do have the search params as form params instead of query params.. But that would still mean a POST, right?

Comment: You can use `@QueryParam` or `@PathParam`

Answer (score 0):

I write my solution for more complex problem: map GET params throw MultivaluedMap to Object. May be it whould be helpful for other.

GET query is very simple way to chat with your server. Even non-programmer with browser url control can execute simple API tasks.

But create object from "get" query is not recomended way (One of the reasons is 4000 symbols max limit).

GET query has MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM by default.

```
// GOAL: create simple in use API (for non-programmers) to call rest service to test functional. User can use any business object field.
//      So need map GET query params to server business object.

// Create Provider and save it in jersey rest folder (for auto detect).
// 
// PROBLEM: "get" query hasn't body and query params don't available get from readFrom prodiver method
//          So use uriInfo for getting query params 

@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public class GETQueryMapperProvider<T> implements MessageBodyReader<T> {
    //[!!!] MAIN PART: save the uri
    @Context
    private UriInfo uriInfo;

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> aClass, Type type, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public T readFrom(Class<T> tClass, Type type, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
                      MultivaluedMap<String, String> stringStringMultivaluedMap,
                      InputStream inputStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        MultivaluedMap queryParams = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
        //create from Map Object
        return ServiceUtils.convertMapToObject(queryParams, tClass);
    }
}
```

And second part solution:

```
public static <T> T convertMapToObject(Map map, Class<T> objectClass) {
    try {
        //[!!!] MAIN PART - MultivaluedMap for each value create list. 
        //But we list only for fields with collection type, for other need take first value. 
        map = fixCollectionsValue(map, objectClass);

        ObjectMapper ob = new ObjectMapper();
        StringWriter json = new StringWriter();
        ob.writeValue(json, map);

        return ob.readValue(json.toString(), objectClass);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return null;
}
protected static Map fixCollectionsValue(Map map, Class objectClass) {
    Map newMap = new HashMap(map);
    for(Field field : objectClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if(!Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())
                &&!Modifier.isFinal(field.getModifiers())) {
            String name = field.getName();
            Object value = map.get(name);
            Object newValue = value;
            if(value != null) {
                if(isCollectionClass(field.getType())) {
                    if(!isCollectionClass(value.getClass())) {
                        newValue = new ArrayList();
                        ((ArrayList) newValue).add(value);
                        newMap.put(name, newValue);
                    }
                } else {
                    if(isCollectionClass(value.getClass())) {
                        //take first value to our object
                        newValue = ((Collection) newValue).iterator().next();
                        newMap.put(name, newValue);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return newMap;
}
protected static boolean isCollectionClass(Class clazz) {
    return clazz.isArray() ||
           Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
}
```